# Parse string to set of data in JavaScript(jQuery) to match series in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I want to format the following data from String to "[set of data](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series)" to match the series in HighCharts.

I've tried parsing it with JSON.parse but, of course, this is not a JSON, so it won't work.

So I have the following string:

```
var str = "[
{name: 'Abril', data: [107, null, 635, 203, 2]}, 
{name: 'Mayo', data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]}, 
{name: 'Junio', data: [1052, null, 4250, 740, 38]}
]"
```

The desired result is:

```
var data = [
{name: 'Abril', data: [107, null, 635, 203, 2]}, 
{name: 'Mayo', data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]}, 
{name: 'Junio', data: [1052, null, 4250, 740, 38]}
]
```

Replacing the quotes with nothing won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it with

```
var data = eval(str);
```

Comment: Better is using JSON.parse();

Comment: That was exactly the problem, JSON.parse() wouldn't work.